# FullPage.JS continuous Scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, fullpage.js

Just starting to use fullPage.js and loving it so far.
Anyhow, when implementing continuous effect and you're on the last section, scrolling down it sends you to the first section, but it looks like it loads two times, or like it very fast goes to the second section and then to the first I removed all other scripts and tried again, but same problem.

Also, header disappears  when you scroll to first section again, after last section.

Here is the link:
http://sedmica.rs/problem/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It works as expected as you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/534/) with your same initialisation.

I believe you have some problem related with the use of the class 'slide' for another one of your plugins. That's making fullPage.js throw the an error in the javascript console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined
```

To solve this, if you are not planning to make use of the fullPage.js sliders and you rather prefer using some other plugin for that, make use of the opton `slideSelector` to set the value to any other string different from `slide`.

From [fullPage.js docs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js):

> slideSelector: (default .slide) Defines the jQuery selector used for the plugin slides. It might need to be changed sometimes to avoid problem with other plugins using the same selectors as fullpage.js.

Comment: I changed the name, but it's still the same. I already tried to remove plugins and see if it will change anything and no - it's the same. With or without other plugins - it does not work

Comment: @MomciloPopov well, you will have to prove it by providing a reproduction of the problem. Otherwise, we only have your previous link to study it and there are external plugins there and the use of the `slide` class.

Comment: Oh, I did it!

The problem was: 

`loopBottom: false,
loopTop: false,`

Comment: But I still have another problem. I thought the same solution for both problems, but it seems not.

When you find you on the first section, and stroke it to the next slide (right), on the left you can see a little piece of the first slide. 

The problem is in the jquery.fullPage.js file, but I can not find where

Comment: You are not managing the slides with fullPage.js, so I dont see why the problem should be with it.

Comment: I do not know, but when I delete `<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>` part, it looks fine.